# error: 'midfielder1' not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object

I'm currently having some difficulty with objects and classes. I'm creating the objects, in this case football players in one function of a class then trying to display their details in another function.
This is the function where the objects are created,

```
void create_all_players(){
Midfielder *midfielder1= new Midfielder("Jordan Lewis");
Midfielder *midfielder2= new Midfielder("David Armitage");
Midfielder *midfielder3= new Midfielder("Tom Rockliff");
Midfielder *midfielder4= new Midfielder("Gary Ablett");
Midfielder *midfielder5= new Midfielder("Dyson Heppel");
Midfielder *midfielder6= new Midfielder("Scott Pendlebury");
Midfielder *midfielder7= new Midfielder("Michael Barlow");
Midfielder *midfielder8= new Midfielder("Jack Steven");
}
```

and this is the function where i am trying to output the players details,

```
void display_all_players(){

cout<<midfielder1->Player_Details()<<endl;
cout<<midfielder2->Player_Details()<<endl;
cout<<midfielder3->Player_Details()<<endl;
cout<<midfielder4->Player_Details()<<endl;
cout<<midfielder5->Player_Details()<<endl;
cout<<midfielder6->Player_Details()<<endl;
cout<<midfielder7->Player_Details()<<endl;
cout<<midfielder8->Player_Details()<<endl;
}
```

but when i try to run the program i get the error, 'midfielder1' was not declared in this scope, for all of the objects. How do i reference the object without an error occuring in the display_all_players function?
In case other information is needed, midfielder is a class that inherits from the player class below.

Player.h

```
    #ifndef PLAYER_H
    #define PLAYER_H
    #include <string>

    class Player
    {
        public:
            Player();
            Player(std::string);
            std::string Name;
            std::string Get_Name();
            virtual std::string Player_Details();
    };

    #endif // PLAYER_H
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Midfielder.h"
using namespace std;

Player::Player():Name("Default"){}

Player::Player(string Name){
this->Name=Name;
}


string Player::Player_Details(){

return "Player : " + this->Name ;
}
```

Midfielder.h

```
#ifndef MIDFIELDER_H
#define MIDFIELDER_H
#include "Player.h"

class Midfielder : public Player
{
    public:
        Midfielder();
        Midfielder(std::string);
        virtual std::string Player_Details();
};

#endif // MIDFIELDER_H
```

and Midfielder.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Midfielder.h"
using namespace std;

Midfielder::Midfielder(){}

Midfielder::Midfielder(string Name){
this->Name=Name;
}


string Midfielder::Player_Details(){

return "Midfielder : " + this->Name;
}

}
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: The compiler error message is quite clear. Why would you expect `midfielder1` to be visible in `display_all_players`? It is a local variable of a different function.

Comment: What could i do to access midfielder1 etc in the display_all_players function? I'm fairly new to programming and c++ and am struggling with these concepts a bit

Comment: Read up on classes and data members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created your `midfielder` variables inside the `create_all_players` method. This gives them a function-wide scope, and they can only be accessed from there. You will need to store the midfielder variables somewhere else, like globally (outside any functions).

Comment: I created them outside of a function now and it seems to be working, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you could mark this as the solution it would be great.